# How to find cell containing string in entire worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to find a cell in a worksheet containing a specific string.

I won't know precisely how many columns or rows there will be in the spreadsheet, hence why I wanted to do it with `CurrentRegion`.

This is what I was trying:

```
=FIND("Data String", Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
```

Comment: .address would reveal the cell, press f1 on FIND and it will show you then help and what it returns, be careful of a `nothing` return instead of `range`

Comment: You are mixing up the Excel function `FIND` and the VBA `Range` method `Find`.  Which one are you trying to use?  (Hopefully the `Range.Find` method.  The Excel function won't help you.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should have a look into the Microsoft References: [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

```
 .Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
```

Example:

```
Dim rngFound as Range
With Worksheets("MySheetName").Cells
    Set rngFound  = .Find("MySearchString", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then 
        'something is found
    else
        'nothing found
    End If
End With
```

*searches the whole sheet*

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
 FindString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value
```

---------- This will select the next `Cell` in range with the `inputbox` value

```
Sub Find_First()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

[Find Value](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm)

Comment: Tell me if it helped you

Comment: Thanks, yes it definitely has, I will use the Set Rng in some of my sub-routines. Thanks a lot!